# How to download wordcloud as picture in react-wordcloud?

Tags: reactjs, word-cloud

How to download wordcloud as picture in react-wordcloud? Or is there any react packages that can plot wordcloud and download the pic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do it..

```
import React, {createRef} from 'react';
import ReactWordcloud from 'react-wordcloud';
import { saveSvgAsPng } from 'save-svg-as-png';
import {Button} from 'antd';

const saveWordCloudToImage= () => {
   const wordcloudRef = createRef();
//   const words = //your words object;


   const handleSave = () => {
        const svgElement = wordcloudRef.current.querySelector('svg');
        saveSvgAsPng(svgElement, 'wordcloud.png');
   };

   return (
      <>
          <span ref={wordcloudRef}>
             <ReactWordcloud  words={words}/>
          </span>
          <Button onClick={handleSave}>Save</Button>
      </>
   )
};
```

Comment: Well, my code is the answer to your question. It actually downloads wordcloud as picture in react-wordcloud.

Comment: It's not my question. I'm just saying that doing "this is the answer" isn't as high of quality as "This the answer because ... and you need to avoid ..."

Comment: Here is a working example i made on stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wvqsph)
Explaining what the code does, this method 'handleSave' is the key to save the picture, i created a reference and and linked to the span where ReactWordCloud component is so i can get access to the SVG dom element of it.
This line 'wordcloudRef.current.querySelector('svg')' is equivalent of js function 'GetElementByTagName', that means i selected the SVG element and converted to png using this library 'save-svg-as-png'.
Obs: I´m new here, sorry if my first comment didn´t answer your question.

Comment: If this is what you was looking for, can you upvote this solution?